# Sort ToDoList by alphabetically - completed OR Incompleted Tasks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

```
var taskList =[ 
{completed:false,task:"to home work"}, 
{completed:true,task:"test"},
{completed:true,task:"app"},
{completed:false,task:"doing work"},
{completed:false,task:"sleeping"}, 
{completed:true,task:"to do"},
{completed:true,task:"to home work"},
{completed:false,task:" work"},];
```

This is a list I am showing this list as below

```
COMPLETED TASK           IMCOMPLE TASK
test                      to home work
app                       doing work
to do                     sleeping
to home work              work
```

Now I want to sort each list alphabetically - one by one without effecting other list

like
if I want to sort completed TASK then just sort that list dont touch incomple TASK.

Comment: How are you displaying the list?

Comment: @EricSvitok Currently i am using filter to show list. By using Filter i am getting two seperate lists.

var completedTasks = tasks.filter((task) => task.completed);

Comment: What have you tried? Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve]. You may also want to read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Commentary is good for asking clarifying questions, but you should integrate your answer into your question by editing, to make it "self contained".

Comment: Just grammar fix, nothing more to add for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sort method and ignore sorting the tasks who's completed value is specified.

In this example, you can pass **true** to the **sortTasks** function to sort completed tasks, and **false** to sort incomplete tasks.

```js
        var taskList =[ 
          {completed:false,task:"z"}, 
          {completed:true,task:"d"},
          {completed:true,task:"c"},
          {completed:false,task:"y"},
          {completed:false,task:"x"}, 
          {completed:true,task:"b"},
          {completed:true,task:"a"},
          {completed:false,task:"w"},];
        
        function sortTasks(isCompleted) {
          return taskList.sort((a,b) => {
            if ((a.completed !== isCompleted) || (b.completed !== isCompleted)) return 0;
            if (a.task > b.task) return 1;
            if (b.task > a.task) return -1; 
          });
        }
    
      //console.log(sortTasks(true)); // sort completed tasks only
      // console.log(sortTasks(false))); // sort incomplete tasks only
      var newArray = sortTasks(true).filter(a => a.completed);
      console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Try running the code snippet. Is that the output you wanted?

Comment: Sorry @eric-svltok but this is not that output i wanted.

Your code OUTPUT 
//last lines
var newArray = sortTasks(true);
var filterArray = newArray.filter((a)=>a.completed);
console.log(filterArray);

0:{completed: true, task: "c"}
1:{completed: true, task: "d"}
2:{completed: true, task: "a"}
3:{completed: true, task: "b"}

I want to show as 

a
b
c
d

Comment: @user10992157 Thats strange when I run the code snippet its showing up in the correct order... I added the filter at the end into the example. Try running it and see if it is in order for you.